# How to set icons based on a condition in sap.m.Column

Tags: sapui5

In my JS view, I have:

```js
var col5 = new sap.m.Column("col5", {
  width: "auto",
  header: new sap.m.Label({
    text: "Late"
  }),
  footer: new sap.ui.core.Icon({
    src: {
      path: "Late",
      formatter: function(approved) {
        if (approved == "Yes") {
          return "sap-icon://notification";
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In debug mode, I checked the value of `approved` but it has `null` value. Please suggest.

Comment: because there does not seem to be any binding here and still you use a 'path' :)

Comment: Hi Ash, Thanks for your reply. Can you please help me with the binding ? I am new to SAP UI5

Comment: this will need some more sample code :p like your data and model

Answer (score 0):

Assume, you have a model with a value "Late" ("Yes or "No") and you want to display the icon in case of this value being "Yes". Then you can use [Expression Binding](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0ce0b8c56fa74dd897fffda8407e8272/7.5.6/en-US/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html)

```
footer: new sap.ui.core.Icon({
  src: "sap-icon://notification",
  visible: "{= ${Late} === 'Yes'}"
});
```